# Error Checking Two Possibilities

Tags: vba, excel

My current code is checking for either lengthListbox or lengthListbox2 to have a selection or it will display an error message. What's the easiest way to make it so it is a selection from either lengthListbox or lengthListbox2 or the message "Please enter project length" will be displayed?

```
Function CheckInputs() As Boolean
    If Not CheckControl(Me.nameTextbox, "Please enter your name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.projectTextbox, "Please enter a Project Name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.audienceCombobox, "Please select an Audience") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.impactCombobox, "Please select Impact Type") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.lengthListbox, "Please select a current year month") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.lengthListbox2, "Please select a next year month") Then Exit Function

    CheckInputs = True
End Function

Private Function CountSelectedListBoxItems(lb As MSForms.ListBox) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    With lb
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then CountSelectedListBoxItems = CountSelectedListBoxItems + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Function

Function CheckControl(ctrl As MSForms.Control, errMsg As String) As Boolean
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case "TextBox"
            CheckControl = Trim(ctrl.Value) <> ""
        Case "ComboBox"
            CheckControl = ctrl.ListIndex <> -1
        Case "ListBox"
            CheckControl = CountSelectedListBoxItems(ctrl) > 0
'        Case Else
    End Select
    If CheckControl Then Exit Function
    ctrl.SetFocus
    MsgBox errMsg
End Function
```

Some things I've tried:

Trying to enter an error check in the enter button

```
Private Sub enterButton_Click()
    If Me.lengthListbox.ListIndex = -1 And Me.lengthListbox2.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "Please enter Project Length"
    End If
    If Not CheckInputs Then Exit Sub 'check for fields to have values
    Process GetWs(Me.impactCombobox.Value) ' process data passing the proper worksheet got from GetWs() function
    MsgBox "Project Entered Successfully"
    ClearUFData 'clear the data
End Sub
```

I've also tried making a separate subfunction that is meant for checking listboxes only but couldn't make it work within CheckInputs

Comment: Should it be OR, as your post?

Comment: I've tried OR and AND and they both still let the project go through successfully.

Comment: I've just tried `If Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Or Me.ListBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "Error"
End If` and it works

Comment: It should in theory work but I think it has to do with my other functions I have set up, I'm not sure where I went wrong with coding or if I can build it into my current error checking right now.

Comment: have a function, `Public Function Validate_Form() as Boolean` in the form, you can then have `Validate_Form=((Me.ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1) or (Me.ListBox2.ListIndex = -1))*CheckInputs `   then use this to drive the enabled property of the button on each control change/exit  `me.enterButton.enabled=Validate_Form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try two functions little modifications:

1) nest the listboxes checks (see last line before `CheckInputs = True`)

```
Function CheckInputs() As Boolean
    If Not CheckControl(Me.nameTextbox, "Please enter your name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.projectTextbox, "Please enter a Project Name") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.audienceCombobox, "Please select an Audience") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.impactCombobox, "Please select Impact Type") Then Exit Function
    If Not CheckControl(Me.lengthListbox, "") Then If Not CheckControl(Me.lengthListbox2, "Please enter project length") Then Exit Function

    CheckInputs = True
End Function
```

so that the first listbox possible negative check will have the second listbox check decide about the "exit"

2) slightly modify CheckControl (see first line right after `End Select`)

```
Function CheckControl(ctrl As msforms.Control, errMsg As String) As Boolean
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case "TextBox"
            CheckControl = Trim(ctrl.Value) <> ""
        Case "ComboBox"
            CheckControl = ctrl.ListIndex <> -1
        Case "ListBox"
            CheckControl = CountSelectedListBoxItems(ctrl) > 0
'        Case Else
    End Select
    If errMsg = "" Then Exit Function
    If CheckControl Then Exit Function
    ctrl.SetFocus
    MsgBox errMsg
End Function
```

so that no action is taken if the passed error message string is a void one

Comment: This is the fix, thanks again for anything. Do you have a form of contact or an Excel Help Forum user? I have a topic posted in there that is rewarding "coins" for any macro help.

Comment: I'm not getting you: what do you mean?

Comment: I was wondering if you had an account on the "Excel Help Forum" website, I have a question posted up there that is rewarding "coins" (payment) in exchange for macro help.